# How can one live happily vs How one can live happily?

Tags: modal-verbs, word-order, content-clauses

> How **can** one live happily
>
> How one **can** live happily

What is grammatically correct from the above two sentences and also let me know meaning for both the sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a grammatical question. The second one reads more like a title than a question; it could be used as a header for a paragraph.

So, as an essay, you might see it like this:

> How can one live happily? By learning to be content with what you have, and making the most of every day. A spirit of thankfulness helps as well.

or:

> **How one can live happily**
>
> We can have a happier life when we learn to be be content with what we have, and make the most of every day. Keeping a thankful spirit helps, too.

In a dialog, we might start with the question form:

> "Dad, how can one live happily?"
> "Well, son, we can be happy by learning to be content with what we have, and making the most of every day. Staying thankful can help, too."

Answer (score 2):

If you intend the clause to be a standalone question, then the first is okay:

> "How **can** one live happily?" asked he, looking at the sky. (a standalone question)

In the first position we have the [interrogative word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word) "how", next goes the auxiliary verb "can", then the subject pronoun "one".

The second clause will only be okay in a headline (see J.R.'s answer) or as part of a bigger sentence:

> Come here, son. I will tell you [how one **can** live happily].

Here, the part in brackets would be an "*[interrogative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause)*".

---

Why do the two clauses differ? Because the first clause is an example of "[subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion)". The word **one** is the subject. The word **can** is an auxiliary verb. When you are just telling something, you usually place the subject first: SUB + AUX. But you sometimes *invert* their positions: AUX + SUB, for example, when you pose questions.

The second clause does not feature the inversion. It would fit in an indirect question sentence:

> Could you tell me how one **can** live happily?

The same "indirect question" word order applies to reported questions:

> She asked me how one **can** live happily.

.. and it could serve as a noun complement:

> The question of [how one **can** live happily] has occupied man's thought for millenia.

.. and as an adjective complement:

> Nobody is sure of [how one **can** live happily].

It can also be moved to the end of the sentence, with the [expletive **it**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) taking its place:

> [How one **can** live happily] is not known. --> **It** is not known [how one **can** live happily].

Compare with the question form, where there's a subject-auxiliary inversion:

> How **can one** live happily? (AUX+SUB) - It is not known how **one can** live happily. (SUB+AUX)